# Excel Active X Controls - Not Working Again - January 2015

Tags: excel, activex, updates

MS Excel 2010 - Beginning of December MS sent out updates that killed Active X Controls.  After several days of research found a solution and was able to recover.  Now, again, 1st week of January 6, 2015, the same issue has reappeared.  A little different this time, but basically the same.  Again the Active-x Controls do not work, and I also receive an error message saying it can't exit design mode, (I am not in design mode - how this turns on, I do not know.), and run time errors are displayed.  Did the cleanup on the "*.exd" files, but to no avail.

Is anybody experiencing this and is there a solution out there?

**Addendum** - I placed a smaller application from my pc to the pc having the problem. Again, it was not work, whereby only a week ago, it was working fine. I started to re-create the small app on the problem pc and did some testing. With the code being created on the specific pc, it is working. Hmmmm... where do I go next?

Comment: Addendum - I placed a smaller application from my pc to the pc having the problem.  Again, it was not work, whereby only a week ago, it was working fine.  I started to re-create the small app on the problem pc and did some testing.  With the code being created on the specific pc, it is working.  Hmmmm... where do I go next?

Answer (score 3):

After discussion with various individuals in the office, I was told Office 2010 was reinstalled on the problem computer.  I researched and compared the dates on the **FM20.DLL** located in c:\Windows\System32 directory.  The dates were different.  The pc where the application was working fine had a date for FM20.dll 11/19/2014.  The date for fm20.dll on the pc that was not working was 02/20/2010.  I copied the newer fm20.dll to the problem pc and everything started to work normally again.

Whew!!!

Answer (score 0):

Follow up to the events above...  After further research I learned the IT department **turned off** the automatic patch updates for Microsoft Office products.  This was due to the previous month fiasco that shut down over 200 computers using ActiveX controls, in the company.  They only allowed Security patches to be rolled out and update the computers.  (And this is what caused the most recent problems.)

Please do not do this!  The Microsoft updates coincide with the security updates.  Without one or the other, you will have ActiveX Control issues.

Also...  Please remember to always delete "*.exd" files in the User Temp Directory!  After any changes to your systems.

I do wish Microsoft would fix that issue!  Nobody likes deleting files from computers!